# Help identifying horror short story collection with werewolf story about a boy who becomes werewolf to avenge his slain puppies

Tags: story-identification, werewolf, anthology-book

I read this collection in 1980 or 1981 (unsure how old it was at the time).  I checked it out of a public library in the armpit town of Stead, Nevada.

Anyway, in the story, some asshole's dogs chase down a boy who's cradling his two small puppies. I think the boy climbs a tree but the puppies fall from his jacket and are mauled by the dogs.  Later, the boy somehow becomes a werewolf and sneaks out at night to kill the two dogs.  But then the boy forgets why he became a werewolf in the first place and now he's just a werewolf.

There was even an ILLUSTRATION, a creepy one, the head of wolf on the body of a full clothed boy. Like a dressed wolf walking around on two legs.

Would love to figure out what book/story this is from.

Comment: Have you tried contacting said armpit library? They may have kept your records on file

Comment: That was petty of me to call Stead an armpit, but the library was just fine.

Comment: I've never been to Stead, but the fact that a search for the 'top 10 things to do in Stead' **all require you to leave the town** would suggest that it's not really a swinging hotspot.

Comment: LOL!  Vindicated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***[Werewolf Boy](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?94535)*** by Nic Andersson, originally published in *[Monster Tales: Vampires, Werewolves and Things](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/600028.Monster_Tales)* (1973).

The story was asked about and identified on [this page](https://boards.straightdope.com/t/werewolf-boy-please-help-identify-this-mystery-horror-fiction/517148):

> In the first short story, a boy is distraught when a nobleman’s hunting dogs savagely attack and kill his puppy. Seeking revenge, he goes to a witch or warlock (don’t remember the gender) who gives him what he wants: the ability to transform into a creature that can kill hunting dogs…a werewolf. The werewolf boy then succeeds in getting his revenge by killing the dogs. To his dismay, however, the sorcerer refuses to change him back into a normal boy until he obtains revenge for the sorcerer…by killing the nobleman.

You can also view some illustrations from the book on [this page](http://the-haunted-closet.blogspot.com/2008/10/monster-tales-vampires-werewolves.html).

[image]

Comment: I marked it answered -- you rock!  I clicked on the link you provided; I can't believe someone answered this 13 years ago!